# Unable to load scapy after Catalina update on MacBook Air. Scapy: read_routes netif = rt[4 + mtu_present + prio_present + refs_present + locked]

Tags: scapy, macos-catalina

Scapy was working fine before Catalina update on my MacBook, I was using scapy with anaconda. After the Catalina update anaconda was disabled (as it was installed in root directory earlier) so I had to move anaconda to home directory. Now after moving anaconda to my home directory, scapy has stopped working. I got the following set of errors while trying to import scapy as shown below.

```sh
from scapy.all import * Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in from scapy.all import *

File "/Users/artibatra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/all.py", line 27, in from scapy.route import *

File "/Users/artibatra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 194, in conf.route = Route()

File "/Users/artibatra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 27, in init self.resync()

File "/Users/artibatra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 35, in resync self.routes = read_routes()

File "/Users/artibatra/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scapy/arch/unix.py", line 82, in read_routes netif = rt[4 + mtu_present + prio_present + refs_present + locked]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am new with this. Could you please tell me how to update scapy to work with anaconda(now moved to home directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that your scapy version does not support Catalina. Support was added in 2.4.3 (https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/2139)

You need to make sure you are using Scapy 2.4.3+. When using anaconda, make sure you are using the official conda-forge repo which has 2.4.3:
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scapy